# Python decorator to check for POST parameters on Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-decorators

I have code that read like this to check if POST parameters are included on the request:

```
def login(request):
    required_params = frozenset(('email', 'password'))
    if required_params <= frozenset(request.POST):
        # 'email' and 'password' are included in the POST request
        # continue as normal
        pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

When the list of required POST parameters is big, this code gets messy. What I would like to do is something like:

```
@required_POST_params('email', 'password')
def login(request):
    # 'email' and 'password' are here always!
    pass
```

Then I'm confident that both 'email' and 'password' POST parameters are included in the request, because if not, the request would automatically return `HttpResponseBadRequest()`.

Is there a way that Django allows me to do this, and if it doesn't, how can I do it by myself with a decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a custom decorator, but you can take [`require_http_methods`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_http_methods) as a base example:

```
def require_post_params(params):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func, assigned=available_attrs(func))
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not all(param in request.POST for param in params):
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return decorator
```

Example usage:

```
@require_post_params(params=['email', 'password'])
def login(request):
    # 'email' and 'password' are here always!
    pass
```

FYI, [`require_http_methods` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/http.py#L19-L43).

Answer (score 0):

i'm sharing my solution;

```
__author__ = 'yagmurs'
from copy import deepcopy
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

def require_params(*params):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapped_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
            """
            Decorator for django rest service to meet both GET and POST request
            """
            error = deepcopy(REQUEST_INVALID_400)
            is_param_missing = False
            for param in params:
                if not get_param_from_request(param, request):
                    error['result_message'] += param + ", "
                    is_param_missing = True
            if is_param_missing:
                error['result_message'] = error['result_message'][:-2]
                return Response(error, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                return fn(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_function
    return decorator


def get_param_from_request(param, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return request.data.get(param)
    else:
        return request.query_params.get(param)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/).

Instead of `require.POST()`, try with `require.POST('email', 'password')`.